# Regex - extract outer scope matched value <table><table></table></table>

Tags: c#, regex

```
string input = "<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Text A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>  <!-- Notice this is an inner scope table -->
                <tr>
                    <td>Text B</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table> <!-- Notice this is an inner scope table -->
                <tr>
                    <td>Text C</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Text D</td>
    </tr>
</table>"
```

I have a series of tables in the above string format.

I want to extract out the content in the first level of all `<tr>`, where the expected extracted content is:

```
Text A

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Text B</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Text C</td>
    </tr>
</table>

Text D
```

I have the following Regex that describes what I am trying to do

```
var regexTableRow = new Regex("<tr><td>(.*?)</td></tr>");

        var regexMatches = regexTableRow.Matches(htmlInput);

        var tableRows = new List<string>();

        foreach (Match match in regexMatches)
        {
            // Get a row of <tr></tr> out
            var value = match.Value;

            tableRows.Add(value);
        }
```

Where the Regex fails is it extracts the `<tr>` from the inner tables instead of outer tables. How do you make Regex focus only on outer tables during extraction?

Thanks.

[Edit] - Thank you, I will use HtmlAgilityPack instead. Similar issue is being faced with this code:

```
var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlInput);

            var output = htmlDocument.DocumentNode
                .SelectNodes("table/tr");
```

Where the inner tables are being picked up instead of the outer tables.

Comment: Regex is not the right tools for this. Use the [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/).

Comment: Use HtmlAgilityPack to parse HTML and extract relevant nodes. Regex is too hardcore for those tasks.

Comment: As mentioned, regex is not the appropriate means. But for interest, you'd need [balancing groups](https://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/377025), something [`<tr>\s*<td>\s*((?><tr>(?<c>)|<(?!/?tr)|[^<]+|</tr>(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!)))\s*</td>\s*</tr>`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3ctr%3e%5cs*%3ctd%3e%5cs*%28%28%3f%3e%3ctr%3e%28%3f%3cc%3e%29%7c%3c%28%3f!%2f%3ftr%29%7c%5b%5e%3c%5d%2b%7c%3c%2ftr%3e%28%3f%3c-c%3e%29%29*%28%3f%28c%29%28%3f!%29%29%29%5cs*%3c%2ftd%3e%5cs*%3c%2ftr%3e&i=%3ctable%3e%0d%0a++++%3ctr%3e%0d%0a++++++++%3ctd%3eText+D%3c%2ftd%3e%0d%0a++++%3c%2ftr%3e%0d%0a%3c%2ftable)  **group 1**

Answer (score 0):

It is frowned upon to do that with regular expressions, yet if you have to, you might define some boundaries, such as with:

```
(?<=<table>)\s*<tr>\s*<td>([a-z0-9 ]*)<\/td>\s*<\/tr>
```

otherwise, it'd become pretty complicated.

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?<=<table>)\s*<tr>\s*<td>([a-z0-9 ]*)<\/td>\s*<\/tr>";
        string input = @"<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Text A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>  <!-- Notice this is an inner scope table -->
                <tr>
                    <td>Text B</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table> <!-- Notice this is an inner scope table -->
                <tr>
                    <td>Text C</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Text D</td>
    </tr>
</table>";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
        
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/XRYJbh/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/XRYJbh/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---